# Php Magento list all configurable products out with simple products out of stock

Tags: php, magento, filter

We have made an xml file for our products and we have a problem.

In our Magento shop all configurable products stay in stock also if simple products have a qty of 0. We need this function for our administration / stock system. We have a filter set that filters out all products that are not in stock (see below). Now we also need a filter for configurable products that are in stock, but the simple products are out of stock and have a qty of 0.

Filter to not show out of stock products

```
->joinField('is_in_stock',
                'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                'is_in_stock',
                'product_id=entity_id',
                'is_in_stock=1',
                '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                'left');

        $products->addAttributeToFilter('is_in_stock', array('eq' => 1));
```

So example:

```
Configurable product: is in stock
Simple 1, simple 2, simple 3: are out of stock
```

We need to filter out the configurable product with all simple products with status out of stock or qty0

It would be great if someone has the answer because we just do not see the solution.

Comment: We where thinking of a solution that could work, maybe that someone can help with a new idea or this one: In the frontend we are using if($_product->isSaleable()): to show the configurable products that are in stock with simple products out of stock. Could we use something like that in the xml feed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a script with which you can find all those configurables that do not have simples with stock. Afterwards you could then use that array of Ids to exclude them in your filter.

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$collectionConfigurable = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'configurable'));

$outOfStockConfis = array();
foreach ($collectionConfigurable as $_configurableproduct) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_configurableproduct->getId());
    if (!$product->getData('is_salable')) {
       $outOfStockConfis[] = $product->getId();
    }
}
```

Then use this to remove the configurable products which are not saleable from your collection:

```
$products->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',array('nin' => $outOfStockConfis));
```

Comment: Dear Mpaepper would it be possible to include this in my current document and then exclude the products there (see below how I have included it. I just tried to make a new php document with your code but did not get it to work. So set a filter with your code in between? It would be great if you can help

Comment: @Coen The way you need to run it is as follows: put the content in a file "getOutOfStockConfis.php" in your Magento root folder. Also include something to output the variable (I have not done so above...)  like var_dump($outOfStockConfis) as the very last line of code. Then on the command line in the shell execute "php getOutOfStockConfis.php"

Comment: @Coen But, of course, you can also just include it in your existing script and then use something in the lines of "$product->addAttributeToFilter('id',array('nin',$outOfStockConfis));"

Comment: @Coen See also http://fishpig.co.uk/blog/addattributetofilter-conditionals-in-magento.html

Comment: Thanks for the help, but till now it will not work. Tried your first and second way. With the first I get array(0) { }, by te second I did not see the filter working.

Comment: I also saw that you have a German website / company, how long would it take you to set it in the php file to filter the configurable products that do not have simple products with stock?

Comment: @Coen Probably not more than an hour if your store is pretty standard. You can drop me a line at m.paepper at lemundo dot de

Comment: @m.paepper I am a bit furder and I have a question (if that won't work I will contact you). I have now the product list and everything is working fine. I get the child products, the only thing is that with the code: $childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null, $product); every configurable product is loading the same simple products. I have made a function that you can see which simple product names go by which config and he is showing everywhere the same 4 child products. Do you know if I can use a different code for loading child products?

Comment: @Coen I updated the answer to reflect the changes I have sent you via email. This is the code which is working.